# Regex for a specific URL that contains a random number

Tags: java, string, url

I'm trying to assert that a string containing a URL is the one I'm expecting, but the last section of this is a random number. I did take a look into regex and tried a lot of patterns, but I haven't found the correct one.

The URL is something like this:
`https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=??????????` This section is always the same: `https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=` and the `??????????` represent ten random digits.

I can remove the first part and assert that the remaining is a 10-digit string, but I'm looking for the regular expression to validate the complete URL.

These examples should match:

```
https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=1234567890
https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=9876543210
https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=4321123489
https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=1265678673
https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=7899453773
```

I'm validating it with this code:

```java
assertTrue("URL: " + result + " expected: " + expectedUrl, result.matches(expectedUrl));
```

`result`: the URL I need to match.
`expectedUrl`: the regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\d{10}` to match 10 consecutive digits in a regular expression. Use `RegExp#test` to check if a match is found.

```js
let re = new RegExp('^https://x.example.com/example/1234\\?w=1080&h=720&cb=\\d{10}$');
console.log(re.test('https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=1234567890'));
console.log(re.test('https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=9876543210'));
console.log(re.test('https://x.example.com/example/1234?w=1080&h=720&cb=4321123489'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To match and capture the random digits:

```
^(https:\/\/x\.example\.com\/example\/1234\?w=1080&h=720&cb=)(\d+)$
```

You need to escape all special characters, slashes, periods and the question mark

See here: https://regexr.com/79eva